# Input only Decimal No in TextBOx

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView and I want to validate only Decimal No Should be input in a Cell
i am using window Form and i am generating Column in DataGridView Dynamically

Plz help me

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CellValidating` event:

```
private void dataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == theColumnToValidate.Index)
    {
        decimal d;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out d))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a decimal number");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thomas i am working this on KeyPress Event and done it but problem is that i am not able to validate only on point(.)

Comment: if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
       {
          e.Handled = true;
       }

Comment: Type Ctrl+V to defeat this kind of code.  Validating is correct.